# Openlayers vector layer external graphic of unknown width

Tags: openlayers

I have an OpenLayers vector layer and for the points in that layer I'm using an external graphic which is the name of the place. Each place has a different name and therefore a different image width. Rather than having the name centered over the point I want it to the side pointing at the spot (the graphic is shaped a bit like a road sign I guess). I can move the image to the side easily enough by setting the graphicXOffset to 0 but I can't set the graphicWidth because I don't know how wide the image will be.

If I setting it to the wrong value, the image gets squashed. 
If I don't set the graphicHeight and graphicWidth the image doesn't appear.

The only idea I have at the moment is to make the images a fixed width with the extra space being transparent, but that area would still be clickable which would be very strange to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Are you storing filename for icon in feature's attributes and using attribute replacement to set externalGraphic, ie:

```
'externalGraphic': '${icon}'
```

You could create predefined lookup table for all images and use style's or stylemap's context function:

```
var style = new OpenLayers.Style({
    externalGraphic: '${icon}',
    graphicWidth: '${getWidth}',
    /* etc... */
}, {
    context: {
        getWidth: function(feat) {
            var lookup = {
                'london.png': 120,
                'manchester.png': 150
            }
            var defaultWidth = 100;
            return lookup[feat.attributes.icon] || defaultWidth;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The externalGraphic attribute is a url to a webservice that will produce a PNG for me. I won't know beforehand quite what the width will be because that depends on the webservice's choice of fonts and padding around the text.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add an event listener to the layer for `'beforefeatureadded'`
2. Make a synchronous AJAX call to another web service method that returns the image size.
3. Then set the `width` and `height` as attributes of the feature.
4. Use `${widthAttr}`, `${heightAttr}` replacement in the style.

Comment: I'm sad that this is the best solution